# Where to put helper functions in a phoenix project?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In a phoenix / elixir project: What is a good place to put helper functions. For example: I use [Timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) to deal with dates but I have to do some transformations on the returned struct to use it with my DB driver (one uses the key :min, the other :minute, etc). I don't want to repeat this piece of code in every model and would write a simple function that does that. What would be a good place to put this? Just in a module within the /lib folder? Are there any guidelines on how to organize this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I don't think there are guidelines yet. You can create modules grouped by topic, like `MyApp.TimexHelpers` and then import those at the places you actually want to use the helpers.

The main difference between `lib` and `web` for Phoenix before 1.2 is the reloading behaviour. For changes under `lib` to take effect you need to restart your server. So I tend to put most stuff under `web` to make development easier. Maybe `web/helpers`...

Since Phoenix 1.2 "the lib/ directory is now code reloaded by default along with web/ in development". See [Changelog](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/823b673fc70a46c0d4af2071eeb278c233a75cd9/CHANGELOG.md).